# I need to store '/' separated strings in a tree-like structure in C#, how should I do it?

Tags: c#, .net, tree, trie, dawg

I am trying to store the parts of a long string in an efficient tree-like structure, I have searched but most of the implementations are for searching within words... let me try to explain what I mean with an example, if I have:

```
/potato/carrot/tomato
/potato/carrot/pea
/potato/lettuce
```

My initial thoughts were that this should look like this

```
potato
 - carrot
   -tomato
   -pea
 - lettuce
```

and as far as I have searched, the really efficient search trees (such as DAWG and Tries) are for storing the words as characters and I am not sure how should I go with it. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: As far as persistence is concerned, I don't need to store the tree so I thought of keeping it in memory for as long as the program is running.

Edit2: As far as the storing of children is concerned, I ended up using [HybridDictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.hybriddictionary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which are more efficient than Dictionaries and everything works pretty fast now, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Where do you want to store this information? A database? A file? An object?

Comment: wops, forgot to mention that. I don't really need any persistence so I thought of keeping everything in memory for as long as the program runs but I am open to any ideas.

Comment: How big is the original list? Will you need sorting, querying or adding to be most efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it in memory, you might use this pattern I recently encountered:

```
class Vegetable : Dictionary<string, List<Vegetable>>
```

Depending on what you want to do with it (search, count, sort) you can implement helper methods inside that class.

Comment: Is extending the Dictionary class efficient? I mean I know it'd make everything simpler but at what cost?

Comment: It depends on how important that cost is. If you have some tens of objects in the whole construction, or possibly up to some hundreds, the cost may very well be ignored. However, if you are adding thousands of objects and performance is an issue, you'd better benchmark beforehand.

Comment: Actually I am using this to control the number of children each node has to around 1500

Answer (score 0):

I think DAWG is a good way to go... have a look at this project, although it could do with some optimisation it's in C# and although it's several years old, the algorithm hasn't changed in that time.

[DawgSharp](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetperls-controls/downloads/detail?name=DawgSharp-May2008.7z&can=2&q=)

It contains method such as MakeDawg, FindNodeDepth etc

"This program takes a plain text file, consisting of only lines of the 26 lowercase English characters. It generates a prefix- and suffix-combined tree that is more efficient than many data structures that would store the same information. This generator code is very slow, but it does work. It can take minutes. It needs to be optimized, and the algorithm does need improvement, but I haven't put a lot of effort into it because it is not run often in my programs."

[Heres another interesting approach in tutorial format.](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/283006-the-dawg-directed-acyclic-word-graph/)

[And heres another interesting break down](http://archive.is/fF9Mv)